# What exactly does 'void' do?

Tags: java

Consider the following code:

```
 float temp ; 
 void setTemperature(float newTemp) 
 { 
    temp = newTemp; 
 }
```

In this example, a void method is used. My background is in C (not advanced though). In C, a void means a function does not return any value (simplest thing I ever learned in C). However, in Java, it seems quite a bit more confusing. The method created is `void`, and it uses the variable declared outside the method, and even modifies it.
So, how does the method get access to modify it, when it is so-called `void`?

Comment: It means *exactly* the same thing as it does in C. And last time I looked, C also has variable scoping.

Comment: Methods of the same class always have access to class variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`void` is a return type of the method. A `void` method can modify the value without returning it.

```
float temp ;
/*Here you are just setting up the value
 * the method is not returning anything so
 * it should be called like this obj.setTemperature(20.0);
 */
void setTemperature(float newTemp) 
{ 
   temp = newTemp; 
}

/*Here you are retrieving the value thats why
 * While calling you should store the result
 * in a variable like this: float num= obj.getTemperature();
 */
float getTemperature() 
{ 
   return temp;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In your example:

```
float temp;

void setTemperature(float newTemp)
{
    temp = newTemp;
}
```

What this code does is:

- Declare a variable `temp`
- Declare a method `setTemperature` with the keyword `void`, this says the method won't return any value. This method is receiving a parameter `newTemp`

  - This method, when called, assigns `newTemp` to `temp`

To answer your question, the keyword `void` is not related with having access to variables, it just means that the function won't return any value.

**PS:** You may want to read about Java scopes on Internet.

Comment: The field is not `private`. It has default access.

Answer (score 2):

Void means it does not return anything. You can not write `return` statements in `void` methods, meaning that you can not write `return x;`, but you can write `return;`.

Comment: You very well can write a `return` statement, but the expression has to be empty.

Answer (score 1):

Consider this fragment of a C program.  Forgive me if I've made syntax errors - it's many years since I programmed C.

```
typedef struct {
   float value;
} Temperature;

void setTemperatureValue(Temperature *toModify, float newValue) {
   toModify->value = newValue;
}
```

This is very much like the line of Java that you quoted.  It has a function that does some stuff, and returns nothing; and the word `void` is used to indicate that the function returns nothing.

In Java, we have methods instead of functions, but the meaning is the same.  `void` means "this method returns nothing, even though it might do stuff to the arguments that are passed in.

Java does not have anything quite analogous to the `(void *)` pointers in C.